# What is meant by the verb "ship" in this context?

Tags: verbs, american-english, slang, internet

[Getting along with a possibly passive-aggressive coworker because of different political beliefs [closed]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/getting-along-with-a-possibly-passive-aggressive-coworker-because-of-different-p?rq=1)

> Everyone in the office, including the girl, was **shipping** me and that
>   guy because we have similar tastes in movies, we code in the same
>   platform, we are both reserved in our dealings with others, and he
>   speaks more often to me than to them;

I am familiar with the online colloquial usage of "*shipping*" (thanks tumblr) as it pertains to online "fandoms", fan communities of a particular fictional work. In this context, it means to have an affinity for a (usually romantic) relation**ship** between two characters which may or may not exist in the narrative.

But in this real-life example, I'm having trouble understanding what the author meant to impart:

- Is it implied that the female author is perceived as having a romantic interest in her coworker, because of their shared interests?
- Does it only suggest that the other people in the office superimpose a friendship between them where one doesn't really exist -- in that way, they are fictionally "shipping" them?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ship

Comment: This is new to me, but romance is not the best assumption. More like saying you're twins.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin: I've not heard it before either, but in the cited context it seems quite natural to understand it as a "reduced" version of the "verbified" noun ***relationship***.

Comment: Please include the research you've done. UD has a relevant definition, but perhaps you can find a more authoritative source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it only suggest that the other people in the office superimpose a friendship between them where one doesn't really exist -- in that way, they are fictionally "shipping" them?

Yep! Because it originates in fiction, it's mostly used for a relationship that doesn't exist yet.

Here is an example that explicitly discusses the real-life creation of fictional romances:

> Real-life shipping can be great. My friends and I joke about how we should go on one of those old people single cruises and **ship** people ... and match them up.

- From the [Fangirl Therapy blog](https://fangirltherapy.com/2016/07/27/is-real-life-shipping-creepy/).

Answer (score 4):

'Shipping' has now become a jargon among the 'twitterati' community for 'relashionshipping' rather than shipping a parcel.

Read from [Business Insider India](http://www.businessinsider.in/Everything-you-need-to-know-about-shipping-the-strange-concept-thats-changing-the-way-teens-talk-about-relationships/articleshow/48337661.cms):

> "If you see someone on Twitter or Tumblr discussing "shipping," don't
>   assume they're talking about mailing a package. The term has taken on
>   new life thanks to people, predominantly teens, using the word to
>   discuss ideal relationships between fictional characters, celebrities,
>   and even their own friend."
>
> "Shipping originated in the world of fandoms, which are groups of
>   hardcore fans of movies, books, and television shows. According to the
>   ridiculousy comprehensive  fandom slang guides  of the internet, the
>   word derives from "relationshipper," typically shortened to just
>   "shipper." Relationshippers are people who care deeply about the
>   romantic relationships between their favorite characters - and
>   sometimes, celebrities or even the people in their own lives".
>
> "So instead of saying, "Romeo and Juliet are a perfect couple," a
>   Shakespeare-loving shipper would say, "I ship Romeo and Juliet."

"[Shipper](http://www.angelfire.com/falcon/moonbeam/terms.html#OTP) (-ness) = Short form of "Relationshipper" -- refers to someone who supports the idea of two specific characters being involved in a romantic or sexual relationship. May or may not be the fans' [OTP](http://www.angelfire.com/falcon/moonbeam/terms.html#OTP). When the pairing of choice is homosexual, the proponent may also be said to be a "[slasher](http://www.angelfire.com/falcon/moonbeam/terms.html#Slash)" instead".

More **Fandom Terms** are [here](http://www.angelfire.com/falcon/moonbeam/terms.html#OTP).